# Get directory name from CWD (dirname without preceding path)?

Tags: vimrc, neovim

Does anyone know how I can get the directory name of the CWD without the preceding path?

I'm trying to build a titlestring like this one:

```
{cwd_dirname_without_path}/{file_path_relative_to_cwd}
```

I think `%f` would suffice for the second part of the title, but the first part seems tricky.

Comment: Look up `:h ::.` and the `expand()` function

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several possibilities:

- Use an substitute: `:echo substitute(getcwd(), '^.*/', '', '')` (which basically means, cut off anything from the beginning until the latest `/`, note this needs to be adjusted on Windows because the `\` is path separator there).
- Using `fnamemodify()`, something like this should do it: `:echo fnamemodify(getcwd(), ':t')` (which basically means, return the tail path of the current working directory).

See also the help at [`:help getcwd()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getcwd%28%29)
[`:help fnamemodify()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#fnamemodify%28%29)
[`:help getcwd()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getcwd%28%29)
[`:help substitute()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#substitute%28%29) and
[`:help filename-modifiers`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#filename-modifiers)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks! I have been struggling with this since your answer to my last question :p

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, @Rotareti: I tried to use this solution just now, and it didn't work for me (neither option did). Is it because I'm using NeoVim? I tried both `:set titlestring=%{fnamemodify(getcwd(), ':t')}` (vim says `E518: Unknown option: ':t')}`) and `:set titlestring=%{substitute(getcwd(), '^.*/', '', '')}` (vim says `E518: Unknown option: '^.*/',`). When I do the echo commands within vim they work perfectly, so clearly the problem is how I am inserting these functions into the title-setting command. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: are you using this from some modeline? It looks like your vim chokes on the spaces, so you can try to remove those, not sure if this will help. Also, try to debug this starting from `vim --clean`

Comment: I am using these commands from within vim (e.g., in Normal mode, I type `:` and then the rest of the command). I tried it with `vim --clean` and got the same result. But then I tried `:set titlestring=%{substitute(getcwd(),'^.*/','','')}` in my full `nvim` configuration *without the spaces* and it worked! Thank you